# Change Button text in Kendo Ui Grid Popup Window

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc-4, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I've got a Kendo UI Grid that loads a popup when creating a new or editing an existing record.

I struggling to find a way to change the change the text of the Update button to "Save" when I'm creating a new record (it currently says "Update" - and its not correct).

I was able to change the title of the popup window, but my question is: how do I change the button text?

This is the code:

```
 $("#grid").kendoGrid({
            dataSource: dataSource,
            pageable: true,
            sortable: true,
            groupable: true,
            height: resizeGrid(),
            filterable: true,
            toolbar: ["create"],
            columns: [
                { field: "OfficeName", title: "Office Name" },
                { field: "SupportNo", title: "Phone No.", width: "100px" },
                { field: "SupportEmail", title: "Email Address", width: "130px" },
                { field: "SupportFax", title: "Fax No.", width: "100px" },
                { field: "SupportFtp", title: "Ftp Url", width: "150px" },
                { command: ["edit", "destroy"], title: "Actions", width: "160px" }],
            editable: "popup",
            edit: function (e) {
                var editWindow = e.container.data("kendoWindow");

                if (e.model.isNew()) {
                    e.container.data("kendoWindow").title('Add New Office');
                    $(".k-grid-update").text = "Save";
                }
                else {
                    e.container.data("kendoWindow").title('Edit Office');
                }
            }
        });
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

You should define `command` as:

```
command: [
    {
        name: "edit",
        text: { 
            edit: "Edit",               // This is the localization for Edit button
            update: "Save",             // This is the localization for Update button
            cancel: "Cancel changes"    // This is the localization for Cancel button
        }
    },
    { 
        name: "destroy", 
        text: "Delete Office"           // This is the localization for Delete button
    }
]
```

In addition, if you also want to change the text `Edit` in the popup window, you should use:

```
editable  : {
    mode : "popup",
    window : {
        title: "Edit Office",           // Localization for Edit in the popup window
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for response OnaBai

I believe that what you are suggesting would work for a editable grid correct?

My issue is that I want to change the Update button on the popup that I use to edit a particular row.

Presumably it would be hooked of the edit event like the one I've placed in the code above ?

but I'm using jQuery and it does not work. 

What do you recommend in this situation OnaBai?

Comment: This works for the `Update` button of your edit row. For this, you don't need jQuery. Kendo UI uses these labels when generating the buttons for the popup window

Comment: how about for adding new records?

Comment: @Charmie, what do you mean about "how about for adding new records"?

Comment: In the kendogrid, we have toolbar right? Say, we have toolbar: ['create'], everytime I hit that "Create" new record for the grid, there will be a popup for me to key in the record. On that popup, there will be default buttons labeled "Update" and "Cancel". I just find it inappropriate that if I am technically "Creating" a new record, isn't it should be "Create" not "Update"? Can I change these buttons' label?

Comment: Yes, you can. You should define the message that you want to show using [messages.commands.create](http://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/grid#configuration-messages.commands.create)

Answer (score 7):

This will update the text in the button of the *PopUp Editor*:

```
if (e.model.isNew()) {
  $("a.k-grid-update")[0].innerHTML = "<span class='k-icon k-update'></span>Activate";
}
else {
  $("a.k-grid-update")[0].innerHTML = "<span class='k-icon k-update'></span>Save";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
edit: function (e) {
    if (e.model.isNew()) {
        $(".k-window-title")[0].innerHTML = "Add";
    }
}
```